# Blue Prism Genesys api

Tags: blueprism, genesys

We are having an issue with using the postAnalyticsConversationsDetailsQuery Genesys API in Blue Prism. It returns a HTTP code 400/bad request from every request sent. Other Genesys APIs are working ok.

I've tried a few different variations of the JSON query to try and get it working but it doesn't accept anything. I have access to Genesys via a browser so I can pull the JSON queries from the dev tools and use those queries in Blue Prism but again nothing works.

Just wondering has anyone got the format of the JSON query working?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: can you do the same query in postman on that machine and confirm it works as expected from Postman?